# how to decrypt hashcode? is it the same with decode?

Tags: java, php, javascript, android, string

how to decrypt hashcode? ist the same with decode??
how can i decrypt/decode this code? could someone help me.

```
enter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String a = txtID.getText().toString();
         int b = a.hashCode();
        txtCode.setText(b);
    }
    }
```

like, it will read the codes backward and display the original data that has been hashed and trimmed.

Comment: The `hashCode` function generally uses a lossy algorithm, so this usually cannot be done.

Comment: Indeed, a hash should not be reversed. You need to use crypt function instead, not hash functions.

Comment: Hashes are one-way functions. By design, they cannot be reversed.

Comment: To put it in context, a hashcode is an int or 32 bits. So, even if it could be reversed, the original value could not contain more than 32 bits of information...

Answer (score 2):

The hashCode method comes from java.lang.Object and should (must?) follow the contract below:

- Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
  execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must
  consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in
  equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not
  remain consistent from one execution of an application to another
  execution of the same application.
- If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
  calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce
  the same integer result.
- It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the
  equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
  each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
  However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
  integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
  hashtables.

I am not sure what you mean by "decrypt hashCode" in that context and it may not be the feature/behavior your are looking for here.

For further information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Comment: You can override it however you want (so you could break the contract), however you *should* follow that contract or things will break. In fact you may still break things like `HashMap` and `HashSet` if your object *ever* changes its `hashCode`.

Comment: @ShadowCreeper an implementation that does not follow the contract is, by definition, a bug.

Comment: @SJuan76 I am inclined to agree with you. But there are arguments that say it might be useful in some cases (most of which would rightly be considered ugly hacks).

Comment: If you do not follow that contract for hashCode and other methods (like equals for instance), you will have issues with ordered collections, which may at the end of the day result in a bug in your program.

You can have a look there: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misunderstanding what [Object's `.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) is about. It is by no means a "cryptographically secure" hash of a given object.

Its only role is to obey the .equals()/.hashCode() contract. And the contract basically has one rule: if two object instances are considered equal, their hash code should be equal. And that's about it.

This is a perfectly legal hashCode() implementation:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 42; //legal but useless
}
```

The most prominent use of this function is when used in `Set`s. This therefore include the use as keys in `Map`s. In both cases, the underlying use is hash tables. Which is why the hash algorithm used should have a decent distribution.